# PowerPoint Web Add-In Ribbon Manipulation at Runtime

Tags: ribbon, office-js, office-addins

I recently learned about the js api for web add-ins. I developed a C# VSTO PowerPoint add-in before. Since web apps are quite nicely portable, I thought giving it a try. However, I was using the Ribbon for some stuff and manipulated it easily with the Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon functionality, like adding a login button:

```
                // loginBtn
                // 
                this.loginBtn.Label = "Login";
                this.loginBtn.Name = "loginBtn";
                this.loginBtn.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventHandler(this.loginBtn_Click);
```

As I understand using the js api I won't get this kinda access to the ribbon. I can only configure the Manifest.xml once and never change it, or is there a way to achieve that?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no way to achieve that. All Ribbon UI on a Web Add-in needs to be declaratively defined upfront on the manifest.